# Addressable RS485

Tags: rs485, protocol

I have a requirement to take a board that interfaced with RS232 and put it on a half duplex RS485 bus. The obvious problem is that at the very least the board firmware will need to be altered to be able to throw away packets not intended for it. Unfortunately there is no hardware support for RS485 addressing, so it would have to process every packet to some degree and I am not sure there is enough MCU cycles available given that there are 17 other devices on the bus already.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Is there so much communication going on that you would expect the MCU to starve? Just filtering packets sounds like the logical solution instead of looking for some potentially complicated HW workaround.

Comment: Interface it via a bespoke black box that strips out everything not needed by the "board".

Comment: I'd say connecting full-duplex board to half-duplex bus is much more obvious problem than filtering packets. Is that board TIA-232-E? What flow control it uses? How are you connecting all 9 signals? You did not provide enough data to give you meaningful answer. Without that, @Andyaka's "black box" is the best that can be offered. In the worst case the box would also need a buffer, not just a filter